# Local Storage - Remove Key that partially contains string

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have given the option to my users to save certain information to local storage.
So when they view an item and hit save, I create the key from the item ID. Here is an example of a key with 3 items added:

```
saved-items: ["31919988", "2424334", "6436366"]
```

And if they choose to remove a specific item, I splice the ID out of it where **cid is the item ID**:

```
names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saved-items'));
var index = names.indexOf(cid);
 if (index > -1) {
   names.splice(index, 1);
 }    
localStorage.setItem("saved-items", JSON.stringify(names));
```

This has been working great but now I have a second Key that I need to remove when they choose to remove an item from the first key.

```
saved-items-price: ["31919988_5.88", "2424334_12.02", "6436366_04.32"]
```

So if the user chooses to remove the "31919988" item, I remove it from the first Key as above but I also need to remove it from the second key but **indexOf** naturally returns as false because it's not an exact match.

What would be the best way of matching the two key values together and removing both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just work with *one single* key? You could have an `Object` for each item and use properties like `id` and `price` to store your data.

```
// define items
var item1 = {id: 31919988, price: 5.88};
var item2 = {id: 2424334, price: 12.02};
var item3 = {id: 6436366, price: 04.32};
...
// save all items in an array in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('saved-items', JSON.stringify([item1,item2,item3]));
...
// get items for localStorage
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saved-items'));
// get items except for the one(s) you want to remove
var newItems = items.filter(item => item.id != 31919988);
// save back to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('saved-items', JSON.stringify(newItems));
```

Comment: This actually makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to accomplish by splitting it all into separate keys. I've ran tests using this method and it's doing exactly what I actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `string.split` for each item of `saved_item_price` before processing it.

```
const names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saved-items-price'));
const updatedNames = names.filter(name => name.split('_')[0] !== cid);
localStorage.setItem("saved-items", JSON.stringify(updatedNames));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the key of the array like so :

```js
var list = ["31919988_5.88", "2424334_12.02", "6436366_04.32"];
var search = "31919988"
var index = list.find(function(element, k) {
  return element.startsWith(search)
})
const key = Object.keys(list).find(key => list[key] === index);
console.log(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var itemPrices = ["31919988_5.88", "2424334_12.02", "6436366_04.32"];
var newItemPrices = itemPrices.filter(item => item.indexOf("31919988") == -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let prices = ["31919988_5.88", "2424334_12.02", "6436366_04.32"];
let newPrices = prices.filter(item => !item.includes("31919988"));
```